# Google Mini: Accessing cached crawled file contents?

Tags: google-search-appliance

Right now I've got a Google Mini crawling a directory containing a bunch of documents in various formats. Is there a way to access the cached contents of a specific document in this directory (if it has been crawled/cached)?

I'm looking for the plain text of the file, not the crawled file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the admin interface, under Status and Reports > Crawl diagnostics, you should be able to drill down to the URL of the document. If there is a cached version available, there will be a link under 'More information about this page'.